# Wiered behaviour by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, pausing-execution

I have the following Java Script code fragment:

```
function upoload_TC(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    if(file.type != 'text/plain'){
        evt.target.style='color:red;';
    }
    else{
        var app_data='';
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            app_data = reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);

        if (evt.target.id[7]=='2') {
/* area of intrest begin: */
            var packet_order = get_packet_order(evt.target);
            console.log("1st");
            var app_data1 = app_data.split('\n');
            console.log("app_data: ");
            console.log(app_data);
            console.log("app_data1: ");
            console.log(app_data1);
/* area of intrest end */
            for(var i=0; i<app_data1.length; ++i){
                console.log("3st");
                if(app_data1[i][0] == '!'){
                    app_data1.splice(i,1);
                    --i;
                    console.log(app_data1);
                }
                console.log(app_data);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`app_data` have a long string.

After execution, sometimes `app_data1` do not have any content logged.
Observation: When I execute it step by step in the debugger, `app_data1` has the expected value. But if my 1st break point is after the assignment statement for `app_data1`, it's empty.

How can I fix this?

I found a `call_back` and `promises` to tackle this kind issues for user-defined functions. Since `split()` is not defined by me, I think these won't work.
I believe `timeout` is not the correct way to do this. Is it?

Please find the video of debugger window [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DtVn7J8-wYUjBHaTNhWjVTTGc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The statements you have there will execute in the order written. The log will never run before the split finishes.

Comment: What can be the reason for above observation?

Comment: i suspect the code you provided is not your real code so I can't really answer that.

Comment: @dman2306 I have added more detailed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing the logging / processing inside the `onload` callback. In your example code, you're setting the value for `app_data` on the `load` event, which is fired after the asynchronous function `readAsText` finishes its thing. By that time the logging / processing code has already been executed.

Comment: So are you saying that the code marked to be `area of interest` get executed even before `reader.readAsText(file);` finishes loading `reader`? So moving `if` block inside `onload` should work. - I will try.

Comment: Could you please explain why was the content non-empty while debugging?

Comment: Because when you're debugging line by line, `readAsText` will be finished executing before you get to your line of interest, and as such you'll have a value for `app_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var stringSplit = function (str) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var splittedString = str.split('\n'); 
    return resolve(splittedString);
  });
}

var veryLongStr = "very long string";
stringSplit(veryLongStr).then(function (splittedString) {
  console.log(splittedString);
});
```

Comment: I realise the OP hadn't yet provided his full code at the time you answered, but why would you wrap a synchronous function call like `.split()` in a promise?